# Displaying onlty tables from MSSQL Server 2005 using java

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc

I have a problem with fetching table names from SQL Server 2005. I have succeeded in fetching the table names but the problem is along with the table names VIEWS are also displaying. I need to display only the table names in a dropdown.

My code is:

```
...
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
               "databaseName="somedb";username=sa;password=1234";
Connection con = null;
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rslt = null;

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

DatabaseMetaData md = con.getMetaData();

ResultSet rrs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);

while (rrs.next()) 
{
     System.out.println(rrs.getString(3));
}
```

Here `System.out.println(rrs.getString(3));` statement prints all the table names, but along with view names. I need to avoid printing view names. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can query to meta data tables on MSSQL server. e.g.  select * from sysobjects where xtype = 'u' ;here xtype is type of object and 'u' refers to the table type objects.. see MSSQL server documentation for syntax details

Answer (score 0):

there are two areas:

1/ you not restricted on Db side for view the Metadata

2/ by using aliases return AliasName f.e. Select SomeColumNane as Count returns columnName Count

```
private ResultSetMetaData metaData; //variable
//intialize rslt("Select .....") and thenarter you can call from rstl
metaData = rslt.getMetaData();
//get Column Class (Varchar, Date, Double....)
String className = metaData.getColumnClassName(column + 1);// packed into try catch finally block
// get column count
int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();// packed into try catch finally block
//get Column Name
String columnName = metaData.getColumnName(column + 1);// packed into try catch finally block
```